# Display an image inside Marker's infowindow

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, google-maps-markers

Why when I try to create an onTap function inside the Marker it displays the error:

> The instance member 'context' can't be accessed in an initializer. Try
> replacing the reference to the instance member with a different
> expressiondart(implicit_this_reference_in_initializer)

I want to show an image when the user taps the marker!

**The code:**

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();

  Iterable markers = [];

  Iterable _markers = Iterable.generate(
    Locations.list.length,
    (index) {
      return Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(Locations.list[index]['id']),
        position: LatLng(
          Locations.list[index]['lat'],
          Locations.list[index]['lon'],
        ),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(
          title: Locations.list[index]["title"],
        ),
        onTap: () {
          showDialog(context: context
          ...
          );
        },
      );
    },
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    setState(
      () {
        markers = _markers;
      },
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Maps Sample App'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],
        ),
        body: GoogleMap(
          mapToolbarEnabled: false,
          mapType: MapType.normal,
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
              target: LatLng(47.0603815, 15.4248164), zoom: 12.8),
          onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
            _controller.complete(controller);
          },
          markers: Set.from(markers),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**The Location class:**

```
class Locations {
  static List<Map<String, dynamic>> list = [
    {"title": "one", "id": "1", "" "lat": 47.0357058, "lon": 15.3988135},
    {
      "title": "two",
      "id": "2",
      "image": Image.asset('assets/images/1.Radlader.jpg'),
      "lat": 47.038418,
      "lon": 15.442134
    },
    {"title": "three", "id": "3", "lat": 47.061431, "lon": 15.424807},
    {"title": "four", "id": "4", "lat": 47.092762, "lon": 15.404409},
    {"title": "five", "id": "5", "lat": 47.051198, "lon": 15.438810},
    {"title": "six", "id": "6", "lat": 47.081459, "lon": 15.453190},
  ];
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Checking the code, I realised the problem was the markers inside the _MyAppState